# Is it possible to change the color depth in Ubuntu 18.04 Minimal/CLI?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, color-depth

Is it possible? I've been looking for almost a week, and I've found nothing that says it can or can't be done. If it's possible, how would I do it?